# Calculate Statistics over multiple DataSets using R or some other statistics package called from C#

Tags: c#

Looking for best way to calculate statistics (like Shapiro–Wilk test ) for multiple datasets and get back the calculations. I can do it in R-Gui one dataset at a time manually but wondering if I can somehow write a C# pgm to call Sql-Server then pass the dataset to some Statistics package like R ???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours is a somewhat broad question but, in principle, you may explore the following approach:

- A .NET program reads data from a database and writes that data on text files
- The .NET program "spawns" the R interpreter (as a process), which executes a R script
- The R script reads data from the text files, computes statistics, and writes the results on  text files
- the .NET program reads the results produced by the R script from the text files

I've had some success with this workflow in the past. I wasn't aware of any usable integration options for R and .NET back then -- you may also check whether you can find something for a more "refined" integration between the two. For example, I know a COM interface is available [here](http://cran.r-project.org/contrib/extra/dcom/) .